# How to prevent excel from automatically updating value of a cell once it records it ? Ive elaborated below:

Tags: excel

Im using if function to check for a condition and record value of cell (say A1). Lets say A1=5 I want the cell (B1) to stop updating once a value has been recorded.
Something like, if(condition=True, A$1, stay as you are)

When the condition is true, b1 will hold the value of A1. But once it gets this value, it will not go away.
I tried using protect worksheet but that keeps the formula live. The turn of automatic calculation might not solve this either. Using circular reference, the old cell retains its value but cells in B2 to B20...  (when formula is dragged down) also get the value of 5, instead of staying blank

Answer (score 0):

You already have the solution with "if(condition=True, A$1, stay as you are)" but you need to put your logic into the context of Excel's capabilities.

The first rule to observe is that no formula can write to a cell other than the one it resides in. So, please amend your formula: [B1] =If(condition=True, [new value], [stay as you are]). The formula must be in B1 because it's B1 that should be changed. However, this probably causes a conundrum because B1 already has a value and therefore can't also contain a formula. So, in effect you are asking your formula to change another cell and Excel can't do that.

VBA can do whatever the user can do. Therefore you could use VBA with this logic. IF([B1 is empty], [assign the value from A1], [don't change]). In VBA script that would look like this:-

```
With Cells(1, "B")
    If .Value = Empty Then .Value = Cells(1, "A").Value
End With
```

That's the code but you still need a way to call it, and that depends upon the design of your worksheet and work flow.